# How can I tell which python implementation I'm using?

Tags: python, cpython

Python has a few different implementations: CPython, Jython, PyPy, etc.  I want to programmatically determine which implementation my code is running on.  How can I do that?

To be specific, I'm looking for a function, say, `get_implementation_name()`, that could be used like so:

```
impl_name = get_implementation_name()
if impl_name == "CPython":
    print "I can abuse CPython implementation details. (I'm a bad, bad man.)"
elif impl_name == "PyPy":
    print "Can't count on reference-counting garbage collection here..."
else:
    print "I better be careful..."
```

Answer (score 152, accepted):

```
In [50]: import platform

In [52]: platform.python_implementation()
Out[52]: 'CPython'
```

Docs: [platform.python_implementation](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html#platform.python_implementation)

Answer (score 17):

How about [platform](http://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#platform.python_implementation)

it gives you

```
platform.python_implementation()
```