# Converting numerous ASCII values (in string form) to readable text C#

Tags: c#, python, string, ascii

Essentially, I'm trying to do the same thing as the Python code below, just in C#.

A user will provide a long list of ASCII values separated by commas, e.g., "104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100" and I want to convert them to readable text and return that information to a text box. Feel like I'm making this out to be way more complicated than it should be Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
decodeText = userInputBox.Text;
var arr = new string[] { decodeText};

int[] myInts = Array.ConvertAll(arr, int.Parse);

for(int i = 0; i < myInts.Length; i++)
{
    decodeBox.Text = not sure??
}
```

Python sample:

> > > L = [104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]
> > >       ''.join(map(chr,L))
> > >       'hello, world'

[How do I convert a list of ascii values to a string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180606/how-do-i-convert-a-list-of-ascii-values-to-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
String finalString = String.Empty;

foreach(var item in myInts)
{
   int unicode = item;
   char character = (char) unicode;
   string text = character.ToString();
   finalString += text;
}
```

If you want a little bit of performance gain using String Builder.

```
StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var item in myInts)
{
   char character = (char) item;
   builder.Append(character)
}
```

Comment: Did you avoid use of StringBuilder for a particular reason?

Comment: No,  I didn't optimize the performance. Just wanted to make a code much easily understandable.

Comment: @VibeeshanRC Awesome! This is actually what I needed! I really appreciate you making the code very understandable, still new to C#. This will help me with other concepts as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the input by `,` then parse the string number into a real number and cast it into a char and then create a string using it's `char[]` ctor.

```
var result = new string(userInputBox.Text.Split(',').Select(c => (char)int.Parse(c)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

I do believe you were a good way there with your first attempt:

```
var arr = userInputBox.Text.Split(‘,’);
textbox.Text = new string(Array.ConvertAll(arr, s => (char)(int.Parse(s)));
```

Where you used convertall to change an array of string to an array of int, I added a cast to char to make it output an array of chars instead (I explain why, below) and this can be converted to a string by passing it into a new string’s constructor

This has resulted in a much more compact (and I could have make it a one liner to be honest) form but compactness isn’t always desirable from a learning perspective

Hence, this is fixing your code if it’s easier to understand:

```
decodeText = userInputBox.Text;
var arr = decodeText.Split(‘,’);

int[] myInts = Array.ConvertAll(arr, int.Parse);

for(int i = 0; i < myInts.Length; i++)
{
    decodeBox.Text += (char)myInts[i];
}
```

The crucial bit you were missing (apart from using string split to split the string into an array of numerical strings) was converting the int to a char

In c# there is a direct mapping from int to char- letter A is 65, for example and if you take the int 65 and cast it to a char, with `(char)` it becomes A

Then we just append this

If the list of ints will be long, consider using a stringbuilder to build your string

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation! I didn't realize how close I was, but you've helped me understand significantly more about how everything is working and better ways to do it. I've upvoted (still low rep, so it won't show publicly). Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have an array of `ints`:

```
int[] asciis = new []{104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100};
```

its easy to transform them to an array of `chars` with Linq:

```
var chars = asciis.Select(i=>(char)i).ToArray();
```

And then to the string representation (luckily, we have a string constructor that does it):

```
var text = new string (chars);
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight forward:

```
var data = new byte[]{104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100};
var str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

[.net fiddle sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hM61Ye)

If you need to convert the data from a text input you need to convert that

```
var input = "104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100";
var data = Array.ConvertAll( 
    input
        .Split(',')
        .Select( e => e.Trim() )
        .ToArray(),
    Byte.Parse );
var str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

[.net fiddle sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zk5m5E)

Comment: Good shout, just needs a bit of addition to help him out with generating that byte array? Array.ConvertAll(String.Split,byte.Parse) maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just entered in c#, so you need a code that you can understand.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100";

        String output = String.Empty;

        foreach (var item in input.Split(',').ToArray())
        {
            int unicode = Convert.ToInt32(item);
            var converted = char.ConvertFromUtf32(unicode);
            output += converted;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**ConvertFromUtf32(int utf32):** Converts the specified Unicode code point into a UTF-16 encoded string.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: @Justin, view the answer might be it help you :)