# I am trying to print escape characters using for loop. My motive is to see the values that gets printed

Tags: python, python-3.x

Example:

```
print("\1")
print("\77")
print("\46")
```

output:

```
?
&
```

I have tried below codes but they didn't work.

```
for i in range(100):
    x = (r"\ ".strip() + str(i))
    print("{}".format(x))

for i in range(100):
    x = ("\{}".format(i))
    print(x)
    print("{}".format(x))
```

Comment: Please see the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a list of ascii values to a string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180606/how-do-i-convert-a-list-of-ascii-values-to-a-string-in-python)

Comment: What is your actual question? Many terminal control codes comprise multiple characters, annd do nothing if the second or third character etc is invalid. Probably better to read documentation for the specific terminal you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will resolve your problem

```
for i in range(100):
    r = "\{}".format(i)
    decoded_string = bytes(r, "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")
    x = ("\{}".format(i))
    print(x+" = "+decoded_string)
```