# converting string to integer in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I was trying to convert a string list to integer in python as follows:

```
plain = input("string >> ")
string_list = list(plain)
print(string_list)
ASCII = []

for x in range (0, len(string_list)):
    ASCII.append([ord(string_list[x])])

print(ASCII)

for x in range (0, len(ASCII)):
    print(ASCII[x])
    integer_ASCII = type(int(ASCII[x]))
    print(integer_ASCII, end=", ")
```

but I get this error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

So is there any other way to convert a string to integer.

Comment: Please don’t use tabs when assigning variables or calling methods. It’s unnecessary white space and reduces readibility.

Comment: Can you please show what is variable "plain"?

Comment: plain is just a string input from the user like "test"

Comment: what's the result of print(string_list)

Comment: ['t', 'e', 's', 't'] considering i give input as "test" @rcvaram

Comment: Do you want to convert string to bunch of ascii values?

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna yes

Comment: @shubhanshu-tomar you can use `ord('your_letter')`

Comment: oh you used  it you need to remove `[]` from `ASCII.append([ord(string_list[x])])`

Comment: Check my answer it may works

Comment: "oh you used it you need to remove [] from ASCII.append([ord(string_list[x])]) – Avishka Dambawinna 9 mins ago"
@AvishkaDambawinna

Yes exactly!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of ascii value, your are appending a list to ASCII
First, we map each string character to ASCII value and convert it into a string type. Then join with the join function.

```
e = 100
n = 20
text = input("string >>>")
#This will return int ascii values for each character. Here you can do any arithmatic operations
rsa_values = list(map(lambda x:(ord(x)**e) % n , text))#[16, 1, 5, 16]


#TO get the same you can list compression also
rsa_values = [ (ord(x)**e) % n for x in text] #[16, 1, 5, 16]



#if you need to join them as string then use join function.
string_ascii_values = "".join(chr(i) for i in ascii_values)#'\x10\x01\x05\x10'
```

#### Update

Based on Copperfield's comment
A better way to do following arithmetic operation

> (ord(x)**e) % n

is

> pow(ord(x), e, n)

```
rsa_values = [ pow(ord(x), e, n) for x in text] #[16, 1, 5, 16]
```

Comment: This clearly removes the braces and gives the output but how do I perform arithmetical operations on an individual ascii value.

Comment: I will break it step by step and post the answer soon

Comment: please share the breakdown as soon as possible. Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell some kind of example for your arithmetic expression

Comment: actually I am trying to encrypt the string using RSA so after converting the string to ascii considering each individual as a variable "c" i wil be then doing `c^e mod(n)`

Comment: e and n are values

Comment: e and n value are generated randomly i'll share their generation

please see https://github.com/theEndurance-del/security for their generation

Comment: You can check right now, I have do it inside the list comprehension for arithmatic operatios for each value

Comment: `(ord(x)**e) % n` for each element we are doing this inside the list comprehension or map function both are valid.

Comment: yes `(ord(x)**e) % n` this would give a new ascii which we have to convert it back to a complete string is this possible?

Comment: yeah that's possible 
`''.join(chr(i) for i in ascii_values)'

Comment: sure then I'll try it out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180606/how-do-i-convert-a-list-of-ascii-values-to-a-string-in-python

Comment: when doing `(a**b)%m` is better to use the 3 argument version of pow, `pow(a,b,m)`  because this one does modular exponentiation which is more efficient way of calculating that

Answer (score 2):

Does this resolve your error?

```py
string_list = list("test")
print(string_list)
ASCII = []

for x in range(0, len(string_list)):
    ASCII.append([ord(string_list[x])])

print(ASCII)

integer_ASCII = []
str_integer_ASCII = []

for x in range(0, len(ASCII)):
    integer_ASCII.append(int(ASCII[x][0]))
    str_integer_ASCII.append(str(ASCII[x][0]))

print("\n")
print("INT LIST VERSION:", integer_ASCII, type(integer_ASCII))
print("STRING LIST VERSION:", str_integer_ASCII, type(str_integer_ASCII))
print("FULL STRING VERSION: ", ' '.join(str_integer_ASCII), type(' '.join(str_integer_ASCII)))
```

Hope so this information is useful to you!
Happy Coding

Comment: It does convert it to a multi dimensional list but still i want to convert each element in the list to an integer because I want to apply arithmetic operation on those integer values

Comment: So basically you want a list like, ```[116, 101, 115, 116]``` right?

Comment: can I actually apply arithmetic on a list because I need to encrypt the string using rsa

Comment: Well, it's a list full of integers so it be possible to to encrypt. I'm not any encryption expert but as per my perspective a list full of integers should be encrypted. So should i edit the post to make the result- ```[116, 101, 115, 116]```?'

Comment: Since it is converting the list from ['116', '101', '115', '116'] to [116, 101, 115, 116] is it possible to remove the "[ ]" since after the application i need to convert everything back to a string

Comment: when you do ord() it will give int type

Comment: I can manage converting ['116', '101', '115', '116'] to [116, 101, 115, 116] using map() function but i need to remove the braces

Comment: Of course, @shubhanshu-tomar, just like this- first create a str version of the ```integer_ASCII``` variable by appending the string value of the ascii code to after wards join them together like- ```str_integer_ASCII.append(str(ASCII[x][0]))``` then, to get the string version of them, ```' '.join(str_integer_ASCII)```

Comment: So should i edit the post? @shubhanshu-tomar

Answer (score 1):

Just use a list comprehension that converts each string in the list into an int:

```
list_of_ints = [int(x) for x in string_list]
```

Or if you want the char value of each char in the string (which is what you get from `input()` -- no need to call `list()` on it):

```
list_of_char_values = [ord(x) for x in string]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply it is possible also. Please find about **comprehension python**.

```
>>> [ord(x) for x in 'abcde']
[97, 98, 99, 100, 101]
```

Comment: when you do ord() it will be int, you don't need to do type cast again

Answer (score -1):

this seemed to work for me, you have a list inside of a list for each number.

```
plain = 'test'
string_list = list(plain)
print(string_list)
ASCII = []

for x in range (0, len(string_list)):
    ASCII.append([ord(string_list[x])])

print(ASCII)

for x in range (0, len(ASCII)):
    print(ASCII[x])
    integer_ASCII = type(int(ASCII[x][0]))
    print(integer_ASCII, end=", ")
```

Comment: Please don't post same answer multiple times I have posted the same exact solution.

Comment: I'm not downvoting @rcvaram he his clearly copying my post!

Comment: your post wasn't loaded before i posted mine.